# Converting CURL command for Locu to Swift

Tags: swift, afnetworking

The Locu API provides this example using CURL to perform a location sensitive query:

```
curl -X POST https://api.locu.com/v2/venue/search -d '{
"api_key" : "f165c0e560d0700288c2f70cf6b26e0c2de0348f",
"fields" : [ "name", "location", "contact" ],
"venue_queries" : [
  {
    "location" : {
      "geo" : {
        "$in_lat_lng_radius" : [-37.7750, 122.4183, 5000]
    }
  }
  }] 
}'
```

This is my attempt in Swift:

```
    let LOCU_API_KEY = "<API_KEY>"
    let centerLatitude = mapView.region.center.latitude
    let centerLongitude = mapView.region.center.longitude
    let arr = [centerLatitude,centerLongitude,5000]
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.locu.com/v2/venue/search")
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var params = ["api_key":LOCU_API_KEY,"fields":["name","location","contact"], "venue_queries":[["location":["geo":["$in_lat_lng_radius":arr]]]]] as [String:AnyObject!]
    var err: NSError?
    NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: { (response:NSURLResponse!, data:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            var err:NSError?
            let httpResponse = response as NSHTTPURLResponse!
            println(response.description)

            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                if var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:&err) as? NSDictionary {
                    println(json)
                }
            }
        }

    })
```

I only get an `HTTP 400 - Bad request` for this and various simplifications, like just providing the api_key. Version 1_0 of the Locu works fine, although it doesn't have the features I need.

Comment: Why don't you use the generic http objects that come out of the box? like: `let url = NSURL("https://....")
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        var params = ["api_key":"XXX", ...] as Dictionary<String, String>
        var err: NSError?
        request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
      `

Comment: Still get HTTP response 400 and my updated code based on your example is at top. error is nil, however.

Comment: I would guess, it has to do with the body. It must be that the json being created is not exactly what they expect. You have two options to investigate this. 1- set a break points and print the request body and compare with what they expect 2- you can use a service like `runscope` to intercept your request and see what is different from what they expect. 3- optionally (just to debug) you can hard code your json (create the NSData from a hardcoded json string.

Answer (score 1):

`afRequestOperationManager.GET` is performing a `GET` request rather than a `POST` request.

Furthermore, the request data must be in JSON, whereas you are using URL parameters.

Comment: I thought my `var parameters` was JSON, but I will make sure I understand what a JSON is other than an NSDictionary.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you need to use `.POST` or in someway do a `POST` request not a `GET`.

Also, it looks like this line:

```
let urlString = "https://api.locu.com/v2/venue/"
```

Should be:

```
let urlString = "https://api.locu.com/v2/venue/search"
```

Right? Notice the "search" at the end. That is why you are getting 400 I assume (404 I guess?!).

Let us know if it worked.

Comment: Still get 'Request failed: bad request (400)'
urlString has search at the end, POST is: 
afRequestOperationManager.POST("", parameters:json, ...

Comment: `Request failed: not found (404)` with afRequestOperationManager.POST("search", parameters:json, ...

Comment: Can't believe it! The meetup group pointed out that I was missing the `request.HTTPBody = ` and now it works with your code! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The '-X POST part of the curl command means you need to do an HTTP POST, not an HTTP GET.

Try using `afRequestOperationManager.POST` instead.